What is the adjective used to refer to clothes that you wear every day such as a dress or a Tshirt, not special ones like a swimsuit?
My daughter went home with her dress soaked in water. I guessed she swam in a pool with her dress still on (There is a swimming pool outside).
I want say something like this sentence "Why were you swimming in your usual/normal/ordinary... clothes".
But I don't know what adjective I should put before "clothes"?   usual/normal/ordinary...?
What is the adjective used to refer to clothes that you wear every day such as a dress or a Tshirt, not special ones like a swimsuit?

The kind of clothes you wear every day are your everyday clothes.  usual/normal/ordinary are also all words with the same kind of meaning.  Take your pick!

In India it is called daily wear or everyday+ clothes. The question asked by the salesman, "Do you need daily wear or party salwar/. saree etc.

“Normal” attire is often referred to as street clothes. This diffentiates not only from swimwear, but also from such specialized occupational apparel as a ballerina’s tutu a physician’s surgical scrubs, mask, and gloves, and a firefighter’s coat, helmet, and boots.

A couple of possibilities spring to mind workaday and , of course, everyday

We do not usually think of a swimsuit as 'clothes', or that wearing one meant that someone was 'dressed', so that you could simply ask 'Why were you swimming in your clothes?', or 'Why were you swimming while you were dressed?'.
Note that swimming in clothes is part of many schools' swimming lesson plans, as being able to do so easily is important for safety. Usually, though, these are simply pyjamas and the parents would know about it beforehand.

It is known that swimmers, swimming at the same speed, consume more
oxygen when swimming fully clothed than when wearing a traditional
swimsuit. An increase in energy consumption when
swimming while wearing clothes probably results from increased
water resistance, which hinders movement of the arms and legs [...] In
Japan, more people drown when wearing clothes than when wearing a
swimsuit. In 1998, police officials reported that 1,200 people
drowned in Japan; 25% of them drowned wearing a swimsuit, and the
other 75% drowned wearing clothes while doing activities such as
fishing, boating, or working near the water. The increased physical
exertion required when swimming while wearing clothes may have been a
factor in their deaths. The difference between the energy costs of
swimmers wearing clothes versus those not wearing clothes has not been
fully investigated.

Comparison of Blood Lactate Levels Between Swimming
in Clothes and a Swimsuit


Why were you swimming in your usual/normal/ordinary... clothes?

I see no reasons to have such a classification for this.   Adjectives like these would be understood but won’t make the sentence any clearer than actual nouns do:
Why were you swimming in your dress?
Why didn’t you change into your swimsuit (or swimwear)?
